# Highlight current post in the sidebar page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page added as a sidebar in the blog and now i want to highlight the post when user clicks on that.

How can i highlight current post in wordpress ?

Please give me the suggestion.

Below is my page.php

```
<?php

get_header();
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <?php get_template_part('content', 'header'); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php get_template_part('content', 'page'); ?>

            <?php
            // If the theme is set to display comments
            if (get_theme_mod('uu2014_display_comments_pages', 1)) {
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            } ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php get_template_part('content', 'footer'); ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->


<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

sidebar.php

```
$uu2014_widget_default_args = array(
  'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
  'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
  'after_title'   => '</h1>',
);
?>
<div id="secondary" class="sidebar-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navigation site-navigation secondary-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php if (!dynamic_sidebar('home-widgets')) : ?>
        <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts', null, $uu2014_widget_default_args ); ?>
        <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Archives', null, $uu2014_widget_default_args ); ?>
        <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories', 'hierarchical=1', $uu2014_widget_default_args ); ?>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area  ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

Comment: I would start over. This question doesn't make any sense.Forget what you've done, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess you are loading the sidebar by `get_sidebar()`. But where is your sidebar code?

Comment: I would check in `get_sidebar()` if e.g. the current page id, fetched over `get_the_id()` or some similar function, equals the page of the currently iterated link. It's complicated to help, when you provide so less information. :(

Comment: I have updated the sidebar.php...I am using pages as a sidebar, so i need to highlight current post title in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to add a class to the link that contains the post ID.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
```

You can then write a custom CSS function, put it in `functions.php` and hook to the `wp_head`. This function only serves to echo the necessary CSS to highlight the link.

```
function theme_prefix_highlight_current_post_in_sidebar() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body.postid-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> a.post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> {
            color: #f00;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'theme_prefix_highlight_current_post_in_sidebar');
```

Comment: So where should i add the first line of code to link class and post id ?

Comment: So where should i add the first line of code to link class and post id ?  In my content-page.php, first line is <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>  I tried to add here along with your code to highlight with CSS but still not happening...please suggest on this..Thank you